# Multiple plots side by side in a Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have previously created apps where the plots were placed side by side by using the width attribute. However, for this new app it doesn't work, and I can't seem to find the reason why.

Previous app where it works, [live version](http://188.166.78.89:3838/shiny/regression_towards_the_mean/). [GitHub repo.](https://github.com/Deleetdk/regression_towards_the_mean) Or run using (load Shiny library first):

```
runGitHub("deleetdk/regression_towards_the_mean")
```

The new app where it doesn't work. [GitHub repo.](https://github.com/Deleetdk/classification_multiple_predictors) Or run using:

```
runGitHub("deleetdk/classification_multiple_predictors")
```

The relevant code looks identical to me. What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app where it works uses custom CSS to set `float:left`: https://github.com/Deleetdk/regression_towards_the_mean/blob/master/www/style.css
https://github.com/Deleetdk/regression_towards_the_mean/blob/master/ui.R#L13